# S3 ListObjectsV2 api call not returning contents

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

According to the [ListObjectsV2 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) documentation, when I specify a `Prefix` and a `Delimiter`, I should get a contents element in the response with an ETag for the prefix.

```
<Contents>
    <Key>photos/2006/</Key>
    <LastModified>2016-04-30T23:51:29.000Z</LastModified>
    <ETag>"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
    <Size>0</Size>
    <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
</Contents>
```

I have tried to run this using the python sdk (boto3).

```
client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucketname', Prefix = "folder1-folder2-", Delimiter = "-")
```

But in the response dict, I dont find a contents key. All the others fields as per the response in the example are present.

```
dict_keys(['ResponseMetadata', 'IsTruncated', 'Name', 'Prefix', 'Delimiter', 'MaxKeys', 'CommonPrefixes', 'EncodingType', 'KeyCount'])
```

Is this something which is no longer in the response of the API call. Or is this something the SDK doenst show.
And a follow up question, if it is something on the sdk side, how do I make an api call that returns me this field.

Comment: Probably because it did not find any objects based on your prefix.

Comment: What do you mean by "an ETag for the prefix"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a `Prefix` and a `Delimiter` is provided, the directories within that `Prefix` are returned in `CommonPrefixes`.

So, if there is an object called `folder1-folder2-folder3-file.txt`, then your return response should contain a `CommonPrefixes` list that includes `folder3-`.

Since you are using boto3, it's easier to look at the boto3 documentation for [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2). It shows how the fields are provided in the response.

You can access values like this:

```py
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucketname', Prefix = "folder1-folder2-", Delimiter = "-")

# Objects
for object in response['Contents']:
  print(object['Key'])

# Folders
for folder in response['CommonPrefixes']:
  print(folder['Prefix'])
```

When a user clicks **Create Folder** in the Amazon S3 management console, it creates a zero-length object with the same name as the 'folder'. This is because Amazon S3 does not actually use folders, but it can simulate them via `Delimiter` and `CommonPrefixes`. By creating a zero-length object, it forces that folder name to appear as a `CommonPrefix`. It also causes the zero-length object itself to appear as an object in the `list_objects()` API call.

Comment: In the docs, apart from the common prefixes field, there is also a contents field (the contents field is shown in the question). It has an Etag, where the key is just the prefix, it is not an actual entity. The size is 0 as well. That is what I want to get.

Comment: I have added some example code showing how to access the `Key` and `Prefix` fields. If there is no `Contents` element, then there are no objects with that Prefix.

Comment: Can you please explain the sample response from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#:~:text=Authorization%3A%20authorization%20string-,Sample%20Response,-In%20response%2C%20Amazon. I dont get why there is a contents field, with an ETag when there are no object in that "folder". It is using the data from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#:~:text=Sample%20Request%3A%20Listing%20keys%20using%20the%20prefix%20and%20delimiter%20parameters

Comment: When a user clicks **Create Folder** in the Amazon S3 management console, it creates a zero-length object with the same name as the 'folder'. This is because Amazon S3 does not actually use folders, but it can simulate them via `Delimiter` and `CommonPrefixes`. By creating a zero-length object, it forces that folder name to appear as a `CommonPrefix`. It _also_ causes the zero-length object itself to appear as an object in the `list-objects()` API call.

Comment: Oh, I did not know about the 0 length object. That answers my question. Could you add that to your answer so that I can accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have tried calling `list_objects_v2` with and without Delimiter param but it only returns either `Contents` or `CommonPrefixes` in response but not both. I want both of them at the same time so any thoughts?

Comment: @HaseebAsif It sounds like there are no objects at the level of the prefix you are specifying (or if not prefix, then no objects in the root-level of the bucket). Feel free to create a new Question with more details.