# ListObjectsV2 API EndpointConnectionError when accessed via Direct Connect

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I created a Python script to download data from S3, I used `ListObjectsV2` via a Direct Connect connection, my script is the following:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime 

session_root = boto3.Session(region_name='eu-west-3', profile_name='my_profile')
s3_client = session_root.client('s3') 

bucket_name = 'my_bucket' 

prefix = 'object1/object2/object3/object4/' 

# List objects in the bucket 
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix) 

# Extract the object names and convert them to datetime objects 

objects_with_dates = [(obj['Key'], datetime.strptime(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) for obj in response.get('Contents', [])] 
# Find the latest created object 

latest_object = max(objects_with_dates, key=lambda x: x[1]) 

print("Last created S3 object:", latest_object[0])
```

I got this error:

> botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL:
> "https://my_bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=object1%2object2%2Fobject3%2Fobject4%2F&encoding-type=url"

I found this question and I tried to correct it using the solution, but always I had the same error:

[S3 ListObjectsV2 api call not returning contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70831789/s3-listobjectsv2-api-call-not-returning-contents)

Do you have an idea please ?

Comment: Are you defining an `endpoint` anywhere, such as in the profile (in the `~/.aws/config` file)? Is there a particular reason why you are using a Profile? Does your code work on any other Bucket? Is the bucket one of the fancy new S3 Express 'directory' buckets?

Comment: I'm not using an endpoint, I'm using a profile to identify the role of the user to access on AWS. In fact, I have another code to upload data to S3 is working well, but I'm not used the List_object_V2. This script to download data is working on a machine that used proxy to access on AWS, but when I try to test it on another server (that used a Direct connect to connect on AWS) I got the error.

Comment: the error is in this line: response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix) , even after using the solution of the question that I found

Comment: It sounds like your issue might be related to Direct Connect and its configuration.